# Find variable substring in string with PHP

Tags: php, string, variables, substring

I am about to start working on a project that requires me to do the following:

1. load the source code of a webpage into a string with file_get_contents
2. find a certain substring in the first string, that reads "Your code: 6-digit-number-here, with a dash after every 2 digits"
3. save the first occurrence of the substring into a text file
4. do the same for each occurrence of the substring in the string

The 6-digit number is different for each occurrence in the source code. How do I define that number in the substring, so I can properly search for it, and how can I make it save every occurrence of the defined substring? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the strings found in 2 and 4 the same or different?  If the same then why find multiple times?

Comment: And you'll need to show some attempt.

Comment: please show your code which you try..........

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions to match all codes. In this example the variable `$matches` would contain all matches from the html string:

```
$html = file_get_contents('[url]');
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}/', $html, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: I just realized I am not familiar with multidimensional arrays. How do I output the values from such an array?

Comment: Its actually pretty simple `$matches[0][0]` returns the first result `$matches[0][1]` the second and so on

Comment: Thank you - yet again! First time encountering such arrays and I wasn't sure why I was unable to implode() the values into a string...

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have variable like
`$username = "abcd@somedomain.com";`
`$username = some`

try using this 
`$username = substr($username, 0, strpos($username, '@'));`